# BIND unable to resolve one domain but works on others

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dnssec

On an SMTP server running bind 9.11 for DNS, DNS resolution is failing for one domain causing an email to that domain to fail. There are no problems resolving other domains. However, it can resolve on other DNS servers such as google's or if I run dig +trace. From what I can tell, it's failing due to DNSSEC. If I disable dnssec-validation on Bind, it works. DNSSEC validation tools (dnsviz and verisign's dnssec-analyzer) are not indicating any problem. Any ideas?

Output from dig:

```
dig friendsadventure.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P1-1ubuntu2.5-Ubuntu <<>> friendsadventure.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 4970
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: c146b587dba9a5ee7737a2255db1b01c98ae834561f56f47 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;friendsadventure.com.          IN      A

;; Query time: 4212 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 24 10:07:24 EDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77

dig +all friendsadventure.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P1-1ubuntu2.5-Ubuntu <<>> +all friendsadventure.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 36655
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 8cb7b3c12a7442d2efdac7005db1b04141ec511e65959d57 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;friendsadventure.com.          IN      A

;; Query time: 2465 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 24 10:08:01 EDT 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77

dig +trace friendsadventure.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P1-1ubuntu2.5-Ubuntu <<>> +trace friendsadventure.com
;; global options: +cmd
.                       515510  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       515510  IN      RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20191106050000 20191024040000 22545 . VMJm6mjyJGRlIHIZFqe63o28rV9XrZpMEOjhFIW094xMFd7s2LL49Dfq +gaiZ549QmIfHUNnTAg9ZGeNHgxs+AFobw5/4ag6oieqo6wJdnwLEIcr AdMeHFz6UJ6FA5MKGWTTY/oBfdfCujbCgTxeMKK1sBwrBLrZ70yfH57x 9/tjVsAYagE5sEi+leATrOtBtJf1FfJqa9wD1ps5GAiOODtI7E+FDFsI 6ZvnTqp0d4qnIcNhf1UiUyvhYoFo7OqnJjDo15h/JMMfG1/9Ope1lAba 9Cdg+ufcIpbfIn63ppq6t/gFGsNUO/+E0rTDno2PdKu0w4rmVxN9ouY/ Hs1/Rw==
;; Received 1125 bytes from 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) in 0 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    86400   IN      DS      30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.                    86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20191106050000 20191024040000 22545 . aYmq05+eT68QCPzVN5SAQSvxLh82HUwI7Nh0ioeWsyXALVUvN5CVl3S+ qQFTBiUOGn2vbhHDPrfIfLHLQU11VLFQsS9ZCwG8yUBu1agfcpD8/MZF 3GCrnyhBUhWpaj2UptJJlLk/cncoqX+womKaSgbK3vAYAjsmqQ806hhF dlhM3sQodBmTYFqHTTdnmfJVAZWckES7t0K/wjma6DrMsYJK9rgeiTd1 RnmAojPN/y0M+7rLKc1IuJDZK4YFatjuzZACRVMOtEU33Q8GbNrMHMOO 0o5JfwO7r99tVSMXQR/oCWdhT0ljGTpV1Qcl5VldyLr5rkzRFRRoYys/ cKtYvA==
;; Received 1208 bytes from 192.112.36.4#53(g.root-servers.net) in 38 ms

friendsadventure.com.   172800  IN      NS      pdns09.domaincontrol.com.
friendsadventure.com.   172800  IN      NS      pdns10.domaincontrol.com.
friendsadventure.com.   86400   IN      DS      28564 8 1 EAD936FCAE141DD53D38613B1DDB19BCCAC934BA
friendsadventure.com.   86400   IN      DS      18226 8 1 97AE273935A90AA409038F67E6D3F9D3E262AE0E
friendsadventure.com.   86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 2 86400 20191031053115 20191024042115 12163 com. a5+9EXcT3oFCxHKwk0kua7Y7eV9R9Suyrzj1MKkgbsrT27/5amOQcGQp J2/K8n1dIuQC5wZRRtDkWXxwyagMGEIJf9MQ4mAtZo9SWl9z46SY/Yh7 59bUao4oIJCzslVUUPsgaqsZutGKgDI5a1DIQLWIKMk3N6dVMbDyAx3m VXFlFaKyo1+ffoA283oQpqjNZ6XIuOxzf1RUwNfptTsF2A==
;; Received 460 bytes from 192.42.93.30#53(g.gtld-servers.net) in 16 ms

friendsadventure.com.   10800   IN      A       160.153.128.37
friendsadventure.com.   10800   IN      RRSIG   A 8 2 10800 20191107175037 20191023175037 12486 friendsadventure.com. BW6U7Jn2wmmT4VOdY/Qb8XZJHVyaLp5FqOFdUpDivP9HG0F781V2V+8u bBmrXKsGPpeZYE/g+dTbhhigdGMKoJtiWkFDRZzo1aQd6SpKkho7vgrk sP4QwTpHviTuF/hbU/PlTGeITVN6JNkY5BX420W35B0kFsxGx+eX+r8E zLmTPRtmc9SQe8iR11Vio5ITsZF6m2Wgo/V4brPo0rbCGhfbUPexhNbH TVhEfFKAvk1Cn/6b2nrpg01EU0Mc8TNQ1eB1/Vf8EyyMU5yJfiOXz7nL kTlT0EVMrEE6phAH5iouS3EwJNzgTC7KhcqsPY91cALNC7Vi10gsT+WS f4Vw+Q==
friendsadventure.com.   3600    IN      NS      pdns09.domaincontrol.com.
friendsadventure.com.   3600    IN      NS      pdns10.domaincontrol.com.
friendsadventure.com.   3600    IN      RRSIG   NS 8 2 3600 20191107175037 20191023175037 12486 friendsadventure.com. gmpyOsvAc9v/GnRV4T9EA1RXxGFQ88C8xG2YljPZEwhvnGjT40j3rrrY tnzKAczZzy064jIwDi2FQ3Q09BUKuswnNALxldPaiZRI22xyj9Mal5n6 AxdYhD4k7esmThO2mUbHtb1Cf7hEOpoPYWZZGCQuHUwsAil+PnbdFto1 +9OhY98Xb8koWHWflNGj+v+2XtemqCXsHrvHncKAY8hZg/DjCFfQMJ5N bE5QnTDKw8uhqHLTm83gsT0pBrSQuz1TGCtNVyqlR37PQwkxrXSJBFtb hrSgRusd5SmYq6kgRN/2Z2n3nYbwKjMikk11FxcppwFUcolledJm59Y4 kzoEyg==
;; Received 737 bytes from 173.201.78.54#53(pdns10.domaincontrol.com) in 14 ms
```

BIND debug output. Kind of looks like it's trying to resolve using IPV6 (which I  disabled as part of my troubleshooting).

```
grep friendsadventure dns.txt
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.265 client @0x7f0bc009ebb0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): query (cache) 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN' approved
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.265 client @0x7f0bc009ebb0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): replace
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.266 fetch: friendsadventure.com/A
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.267 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.526 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:503:83eb::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.526 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:503:39c1::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.526 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:500:856e::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.526 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:500:d937::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.526 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:503:d414::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.527 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:502:7094::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.527 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:501:b1f9::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.527 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:503:231d::2:30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.527 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:503:eea3::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.527 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:502:8cc::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.528 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:502:1ca1::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.528 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:503:a83e::2:30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.528 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:503:d2d::30#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.556 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2603:5:22e2::36#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.556 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2603:5:21e2::36#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.592 validating friendsadventure.com/A: starting
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.592 validating friendsadventure.com/A: attempting positive response validation
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.592 fetch: friendsadventure.com/DNSKEY
23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.592 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/DNSKEY/IN': 2603:5:21e2::36#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:28.425 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/DNSKEY/IN': 2603:5:22e2::36#53
23-Oct-2019 17:37:32.287 client @0x7f0bb80019f0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): query (cache) 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN' approved
23-Oct-2019 17:37:32.287 client @0x7f0bb80019f0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): replace
23-Oct-2019 17:37:32.288 fetch: friendsadventure.com/A
23-Oct-2019 17:37:32.288 client @0x7f0bb80019f0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): next
23-Oct-2019 17:37:32.288 client @0x7f0bb80019f0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): request failed: duplicate query
23-Oct-2019 17:37:32.288 client @0x7f0bb80019f0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): endrequest
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bc009ebb0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): query failed (SERVFAIL) for friendsadventure.com/IN/A at ../../../bin/         named/query.c:8579
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bc009ebb0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): error
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bc009ebb0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): send
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bc009ebb0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): sendto
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bb801e690 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): servfail cache hit friendsadventure.com/A (CD=0)
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bb801e690 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): query failed (SERVFAIL) for friendsadventure.com/IN/A at ../../../bin/         named/query.c:7037
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bb801e690 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): error
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bb801e690 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): send
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bb801e690 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): sendto
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bb801e690 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): senddone
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bb801e690 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): next
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bb801e690 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): endrequest
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bc009ebb0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): senddone
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bc009ebb0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): next
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 client @0x7f0bc009ebb0 127.0.0.1#56182 (friendsadventure.com): endrequest
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 fetch completed at ../../../lib/dns/resolver.c:3930 for friendsadventure.com/A in 10.000141: timed out/success [domain:friendsadventu         re.com,referral:2,restart:1,qrysent:4,timeout:0,lame:0,quota:0,neterr:2,badresp:0,adberr:0,findfail:0,valfail:0]
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.277 validating friendsadventure.com/A: dns_validator_cancel
23-Oct-2019 17:37:37.278 validating friendsadventure.com/A: in fetch_callback_validator
```

tcpdump output

```
17:01:19.075437 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 27795, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 68)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.50210 > a.root-servers.net.domain: 41505 [1au] NS? . (40)
17:01:19.076974 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 27796, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.43500 > a.root-servers.net.domain: 14448 [1au] A? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:19.090998 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 41258, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 531)
    a.root-servers.net.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.50210: 41505*-| 13/0/13 . NS e.root-servers.net., . NS h.root-servers.net., . NS l.root-servers.net., . NS i.root-servers.net., . NS a.root-servers.net., . NS d.root-servers.net., . NS c.root-servers.net., . NS b.root-servers.net., . NS j.root-servers.net., . NS k.root-servers.net., . NS g.root-servers.net., . NS m.root-servers.net., . NS f.root-servers.net. (503)
17:01:19.092427 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 17457, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 525)
    a.root-servers.net.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.43500: 14448-| 0/14/9 (497)
17:01:19.113116 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 43966, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 68)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.34191 > i.root-servers.net.domain: 3117 [1au] DNSKEY? . (40)
17:01:19.124800 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56207, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.39560 > j.gtld-servers.net.domain: 55503 [1au] A? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:19.140321 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 3847, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 488)
    j.gtld-servers.net.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.39560: 55503- 0/5/5 (460)
17:01:19.141418 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55938, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.52713 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: 25015 [1au] A? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:19.160193 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 18703, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 457)
    pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.52713: 25015*-| 2/2/1 friendsadventure.com. A 160.153.128.37, friendsadventure.com. RRSIG (429)
17:01:19.187118 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57619, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.48726 > pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain: 13158 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:19.195377 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 56, id 11126, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 56)
    i.root-servers.net.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.34191: 3117*-|$ 0/0/1 (28)
17:01:19.195466 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 46859, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 353)
    pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.48726: 13158*-| 1/0/1 friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY (325)
17:01:19.215932 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55940, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.37145 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: 48829 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:20.016338 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57790, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.36543 > pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain: 22039 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:20.025279 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 32534, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 1181)
    pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.36543: 22039*-| 4/0/1 friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY (1153)
17:01:20.043305 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56055, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.48540 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: 55907 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:21.156737 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58059, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.48699 > pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain: 26029 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:21.167443 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 62141, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 353)
    pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.48699: 26029*-| 1/0/1 friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY (325)
17:01:21.188141 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56250, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.60396 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: 48516 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:22.788241 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58358, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.36707 > pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain: 24787 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:22.798638 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 63148, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 353)
    pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.36707: 24787*-| 1/0/1 friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY (325)
17:01:22.822719 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 56419, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.50584 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: 47747 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:26.022966 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58373, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.43097 > pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain: 54884 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:26.041384 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 50247, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 353)
    pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.43097: 54884*-| 1/0/1 friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY (325)
17:01:26.068980 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 57148, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.48112 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: 39385 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
17:01:26.078022 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 55, id 30505, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 1181)
    pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain > extsmtp3.mydomain.com.48112: 39385*-| 4/0/1 friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY (1153)
17:01:26.097372 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 58379, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    extsmtp3.mydomain.com.57062 > pdns09.domaincontrol.com.domain: 27082 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
```

Config is all default for an ubuntu install, except I did disable IPV6 after this problem occured:

```
named.conf:
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";

named.conf.options:
    options {
            directory "/var/cache/bind";
            dnssec-validation auto;
            filter-aaaa-on-v4 yes;
            listen-on-v6 { none; };
    };

named.conf.local: empty
named.conf.default-zones:
zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "/usr/share/dns/root.hints";
};

zone "localhost" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
```

Comment: Showing your configuration may be needed as the problem is clearly local, the domain resolves fine.

Comment: Config has been added to the original post

Comment: Can you check this https://serverfault.com/questions/639061/network-unreachable-error-in-my-server-logs if it helps?

Comment: Nope. In fact, the debug output I posted is with IPV6 disabled. After disabling that, I no longer see if trying to resolve the AAAA records, but for some reason, it looks like it's using IPV6 with A records. Yet, the packet capture shows it using IPV4.

Comment: I would try removing `filter-aaaa-on-v4` and `listen-on-v6` and make sure to start bind with `named -4` as advised on https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00821  Besides that to debug DNSSEC problems, do your query normally, expect SERVFAIL, do exact same query using `+cd` and if it is then not SERVFAIL then 99% chance it is related to DNSSEC as only difference in second case is disabling any checks, that is any DNSSEC validation.

Comment: Also any specific reason for bind version 9.11? Did you try with a newer one? Current stable one is 9.14

Comment: Do you filter TCP by any chance or play with MTU? `dig DNSKEY friendsadventure.com` is 1153 bytes long response, dangerously close to some MTUs... Try `dig DNSKEY friendsadventure.com +notcp +bufsize=1100` , it sould say ";; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode." while it should work with `+bufsize=1200`

Comment: I removed 'filter-aaaa-on-v4' and 'listen-on-v6'. Bind was started with '-4'. Still no luck. Did query normally, got SERVERFAIL. Did same query with '+cd' and it worked.

Comment: Using bind 9.11 as that's what's in the Ubuntu Repos for the version I'm using. It was upgraded as part of my troubleshooting. After posting, I realized TCP was not being allowed outbound from the SMTP servers (They're in a DMZ Zone, so it's pretty restrictive). I did allow TCP outbound on 53. I also everything through to see if it was a firewall issue. Still no luck. I really thought that was it too :(.

Comment: I don't believe it is an MTU issue. I can ping the remote name server using 1472 byte packets and the don't fragment option set. 'ping -M do -s 1472 pdns09.domaincontrol.com
PING pdns09.domaincontrol.com (97.74.110.54) 1472(1500) bytes of data.
1480 bytes from pdns09.domaincontrol.com (97.74.110.54): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=9.39 ms
1480 bytes from pdns09.domaincontrol.com (97.74.110.54): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=11.9 ms
1480 bytes from pdns09.domaincontrol.com (97.74.110.54): icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=15.8 ms'

Comment: I'm wondering why Yout tcpdump shows only UDP connections. I would strongly expect TCP upstream connections there on modern bind9 versions. You can see response packages from pdns09.domaincontrol.com and pdns10.domaincontrol.com have DF set on the UDP packages, so if one of them is bigger than Path MTU allows it's dropped. You also see that there are more outgoing then incoming UDP packages to the servers which could confirm answers are lost. Did You filter the tcpdump for UDP traffic? May You update that with including tcp if You filtert it and with more verbose output?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was filtering tcpdump on UDP 53. Trying to post the full capture with TCP.

Comment: Here's a link to the full capture: https://www.codepile.net/pile/dVplpeVX

Comment: From my ping testing, I can't see how it would be an MTU issue as I can ping using the largest sized packets with df set.

Comment: What does `dig NS friendsadventure.com` show when run on that server?

Comment: `->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 36836
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 67f550746c024b75593e8c855dc184c40e037fd1be76b5a7 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;friendsadventure.com.          IN      NS

;; Query time: 2480 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Nov 05 09:18:44 EST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 77
`

Comment: Please add output to the main question so it can be properly formatted. What does the bind log contain for this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I find in Your tcpdump is, that it looks like Your TCP connection to the servers is broken. You get one maxsized (1460 for 1500 MTU) bytes TCP package back, then the connections is torn down, acknowledge it and the next package You get is already the FIN:

```
12:52:10.773476 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30033, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    172.16.255.11.53639 > 173.201.78.54.53: Flags [S], cksum 0xa74a (incorrect -> 0xfc0e), seq 1207191269, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2622008582 ecr 0,nop,wscale 6], length 0
12:52:10.784310 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 57, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    173.201.78.54.53 > 172.16.255.11.53639: Flags [S.], cksum 0x5de3 (correct), seq 3333869771, ack 1207191270, win 29200, options [mss 1420,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:52:10.784356 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30034, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    172.16.255.11.53639 > 173.201.78.54.53: Flags [.], cksum 0xa736 (incorrect -> 0x0cb2), ack 1, win 1004, length 0
12:52:10.784493 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30035, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 103)
    172.16.255.11.53639 > 173.201.78.54.53: Flags [P.], cksum 0xa775 (incorrect -> 0x24cf), seq 1:64, ack 1, win 1004, length 6337614 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
12:52:10.805803 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 38197, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 1460)
    173.201.78.54.53 > 172.16.255.11.53639: Flags [.], cksum 0xeeaf (correct), seq 1:1421, ack 64, win 227, length 142037614*- 5/3/1 friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. DNSKEY, friendsadventure.com. RRSIG[|domain]
12:52:10.805837 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30036, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    172.16.255.11.53639 > 173.201.78.54.53: Flags [.], cksum 0xa736 (incorrect -> 0x06e9), ack 1421, win 1002, length 0
12:52:10.805842 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 38198, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    173.201.78.54.53 > 172.16.255.11.53639: Flags [FP.], cksum 0x09e7 (correct), seq 1421, ack 64, win 227, length 0
12:52:10.806044 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30037, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    172.16.255.11.53639 > 173.201.78.54.53: Flags [F.], cksum 0xa736 (incorrect -> 0x06e7), seq 64, ack 1422, win 1002, length 0
12:52:10.806085 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 44626, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 89)
    172.16.255.11.34136 > 97.74.110.54.53: 26250 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. (61)
12:52:10.806877 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 38199, offset 0, flags [none], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    173.201.78.54.53 > 172.16.255.11.53639: Flags [.], cksum 0x09ee (correct), ack 65, win 227, length 0
```

The probability that You get exactly 1460 bytes payload back is not very high. Additionally I can confirm with my server that the response is larger and not exactly on 1460 byte boundary for the same query (1857).

My DNS communication for that part looks as follows:

```
00:57:17.692876 IP6 (flowlabel 0x936c6, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 40) myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: Flags [S], cksum 0x794a (incorrect -> 0x23b5), seq 3083934744, win 64660, options [mss 1220,sackOK,TS val 27470909 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
00:57:17.696289 IP6 (hlim 54, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 40) pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain > myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427: Flags [S.], cksum 0x5462 (correct), seq 1600069237, ack 3083934745, win 28560, options [mss 1440,sackOK,TS val 1680374125 ecr 27470909,nop,wscale 7], length 0
00:57:17.696384 IP6 (flowlabel 0x936c6, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 32) myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: Flags [.], cksum 0x7942 (incorrect -> 0xf0ad), seq 1, ack 1, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 27470912 ecr 1680374125], length 0
00:57:17.696634 IP6 (flowlabel 0x936c6, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 95) myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: Flags [P.], cksum 0x7981 (incorrect -> 0xc999), seq 1:64, ack 1, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 27470912 ecr 1680374125], length 63 17914 [1au] DNSKEY? friendsadventure.com. ar: . OPT UDPsize=4096 DO (61)
00:57:17.700005 IP6 (hlim 54, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 32) pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain > myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427: Flags [.], cksum 0xf185 (correct), seq 1, ack 64, win 224, options [nop,nop,TS val 1680374128 ecr 27470912], length 0
00:57:17.700961 IP6 (hlim 54, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 34) pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain > myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427: Flags [P.], cksum 0xea59 (correct), seq 1:3, ack 64, win 224, options [nop,nop,TS val 1680374129 ecr 27470912], length 2
00:57:17.700986 IP6 (flowlabel 0x936c6, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 32) myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: Flags [.], cksum 0x7942 (incorrect -> 0xf063), seq 64, ack 3, win 506, options [nop,nop,TS val 27470917 ecr 1680374129], length 0
00:57:17.701005 IP6 (hlim 54, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 1857) pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain > myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427: Flags [FP.], cksum 0x8063 (incorrect -> 0x768f), seq 3:1828, ack 64, win 224, options [nop,nop,TS val 1680374129 ecr 27470912], length 1825 33792 [b2&3=0x1] [3a] [5q] [1n] [4198au][|domain]
00:57:17.701106 IP6 (flowlabel 0x936c6, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 32) myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: Flags [.], cksum 0x7942 (incorrect -> 0xe94c), seq 64, ack 1829, win 495, options [nop,nop,TS val 27470917 ecr 1680374129], length 0
00:57:17.701932 IP6 (flowlabel 0x936c6, hlim 64, next-header TCP (6) payload length: 32) myserver.mydomain.net.eu.org.44427 > pdns10.domaincontrol.com.domain: Flags [F.], cksum 0x7942 (incorrect -> 0xe942), seq 64, ack 1829, win 503, options [nop,nop,TS val 27470918 ecr 1680374129], length 0
```

That UDP does not succeed in some or many cases if You have DNSSEC (see same in my case) is not very uncommon.
So we need to concentrate on why You do not get whole the TCP response back.

I wonder why Your machine sets DF all the outgoing packages. (Maybe it's because of Path MTU discovery?)
What devices are between Your server and the public, well-defined internet?
May Your NIC has some problems? Which type of NIC do You have and which type of hardware/VM?
Which features are enables on Your NIC (`ethtool -k ethX`)?
Sometimes there are NICs where some features are broken and could/should be disabled if it is not a device between Your NIC and the public Internet.
You see in my case the NIC is sending my kernel oversized packages, thought the MTU is locally 1500 (and normally the same in internet). Such features can also cause troubles sometimes and need to be disabled in such cases.

Comment: I have no idea why df is set on all outgoing packets. A cisco 2951 router is between the server and internet. It is an ubuntu VM on a Hyper-V server running on An HP DL380. I'll definitely look into what you've found, but it does seem really odd that would only affect DNS resolution on one domain while everything else functions fine. Maybe the remote NS is ignoring the df bit?

Comment: `Features for eth0:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
        tx-checksum-ipv4: on
        tx-checksum-ip-generic: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-ipv6: on
        tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather: on [fixed]
        tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
        tx-tcp-segmentation: on
        tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
        tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off
        tx-tcp6-segmentation: on`

Comment: `udp-fragmentation-offload: off
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-offload: on [fixed]
tx-vlan-offload: on [fixed]
ntuple-filters: off [fixed]
receive-hashing: off [fixed]
highdma: on [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: off [fixed]
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip4-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-ipxip6-segmentation: off [fixed]`

Comment: `tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gso-partial: off [fixed]
tx-sctp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-esp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp-segmentation: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off [fixed]
rx-fcs: off [fixed]
rx-all: off [fixed]
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-filter: off [fixed]
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hw-tc-offload: off [fixed]
esp-hw-offload: off [fixed]`

Comment: `esp-tx-csum-hw-offload: off [fixed]
rx-udp_tunnel-port-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-tx-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-rx-offload: off [fixed]
rx-gro-hw: off [fixed]
tls-hw-record: off [fixed]`

Comment: Also, why would it work when querying their name server directly (bypassing bind)? IE, this works: dig +dnssec friendsadventure.com @pdns09.domaincontrol.com. It's only an issue when querying through bind (running locally on the same server).

Comment: I see I have the same on antoher box. And it should not be a problem here (and possibly never as long as PMTU so ICMP feedback works). I do not have time to look into Your components now, but to have dig comparable, the stuff bind does here on tcp (for validation): `dig -t DNSKEY +tcp +dnssec friendsadventure.com @pdns09.domaincontrol.com`. You can also try same via UDP `dig -t DNSKEY +dnssec friendsadventure.com +notcp @pdns09.domaincontrol.com` (TCP).

Comment: On my cloud server that the UDP dig takes more than 1 seconds until I receive aswer and the answer looks somehow invalid or let's say I cannot find the SPEC to validate it. The 2nd "Z(reserved)-bit" is set, so DNS Header (position 0x30!) is `d3f5 0120 0001 0000 0000 0001` and package very small/no further package. On a Virtual Box VM on Windows 10 Laptop connected through FritzBox/DSL I have no such delay for the UDP and get a full response (thought tcpdump shows only 1500 for UDP despite it is bigger/complete as TCP) with fine DNS header `8500 0001 0005 0003 0001` at position 0x13.

Comment: So don't know why my cloud-server can not talsk EDNS0 UDP with Upstream DNS but my local VM gets an correct answer (I assume on the local VM the TCP fallback would not kick in as it does on my cloud server). I also don't know how to configure tcpdump to show the full UDP package but that does not matter as I see it works there. Maybe You can also try the `tcpdump -vvv -X` to find out about the headers.

Comment: If You use the CISCO device for firewalling or if it is posiible it does it without intention (security features...) try to disable any application level filtering for Port 53 UDP and TCP which is often enabled by default on "capable" firewalls. (If that work, try whether it is capable by using latest software, assuming there are still software updates published in DNSSEC times - or configure the application level filtering to explivitly allow DNSSEC and such).

Comment: Oh wait now I see Your tcp is maybe not broken, it's probably just the same I see for my UDP. The package is somehow displayed as just one full MTU sizes package while it is larger (indicated by `[|domain]` - sorry I haven't been aware of such gochas in tcpdump output if `-v` is enabled) - so redo Your tcpdumps without `-v`.

Comment: Hmm looks like for me the `-v` truncation only affects UDP packages - and only if I include port filter. So maybe if `-v` makes no difference otherwise, stick to use `-vv -X` but filter only on host not on port if You want to see the UDP fragments.

Comment: So what I see for UDP dig `dig -t DNSKEY +dnssec friendsadventure.com +notcp @pdns09.domaincontrol.com` with the full output `tcpdump -vv -X -i eth0 host pdns09.domaincontrol.com` is, that the delay of 1 second is caused by resending UDP query with an longer UDP header (the part that looks about like original DNS header starts 0x30 instead of the part that is a DNS header at 0x13). For that 2nd type of UDP query there is a full response, also with some thing that looks like original header at 0x30). Apparently bind9 does not do this type of fallback UDP query (what ever..) and tries TCP.

Comment: Oh I'm spamming... With `tcpdump -n -vv -X -i eth0 host pdns09.domaincontrol.com` I found the reason for the delay on my cloud-server. The first one is IPv4 (which works on my local VM thought) and the second one is IPv6 and are showing expected DNS respons eheader (the different offset is normal for IPv6). So IPv4 UDP not working there with fragmented packages...

Comment: Sorry, trying to follow all that, but you're saying you're experiencing the same problem on your cloud server?

Comment: As far as the firewall, DNS application inspection was not enabled. I did enable it to see if that helped and it made no difference.

Comment: No I see UDP over IPv4 is not working for my cloud server. UDP over IPv6 and TCP are working well. I told You there was some confusion because of truncated tcpdump output. And how to simulate the failing queries with dig. So may You please do the folowing both dig's `dig -t DNSKEY +dnssec friendsadventure.com +notcp @pdns09.domaincontrol.com` and `dig -t DNSKEY +dnssec friendsadventure.com +tcp @pdns09.domaincontrol.com` both with both of `tcpdump -n -vv -X host pdns09.domaincontrol.com` and `tcpdump -n -X host pdns09.domaincontrol.com` then we can look into whether network is Your issue.

Comment: `dig -t DNSKEY +dnssec friendsadventure.com +notcp @pdns09.domaincontrol.com` with `tcpdump -n -vv -X host pdns09.domaincontrol.com`: https://www.codepile.net/pile/kz4mQQga

Comment: `dig -t DNSKEY +dnssec friendsadventure.com +tcp @pdns09.domaincontrol.com` with `tcpdump -n -vv -X host pdns09.domaincontrol.com`:  https://www.codepile.net/pile/aElJ68Oq

Comment: `dig -t DNSKEY +dnssec friendsadventure.com +notcp @pdns09.domaincontrol.com` with `tcpdump -n -X host pdns09.domaincontrol.com`: https://www.codepile.net/pile/gMkj9kZd

Comment: `dig -t DNSKEY +dnssec friendsadventure.com +tcp @pdns09.domaincontrol.com` with `tcpdump -n -X host pdns09.domaincontrol.com`: https://www.codepile.net/pile/MYBdb7jz

Comment: Ok I will take look. Did these dig commands succeed?

Comment: No, all were unsuccessful

Comment: Hmm yes ok then there is probably nothing new in them. I will take a look later, but this definitly shows that You can neighther comminucate via UDP not via TCP with the server for large packages. The response is quite long (for entries) so probably many other domains have the respose size for such query less then 1500 - also they may other resons that make these answers not work while others work (most probably on "intelligent firewall")

Comment: There must be defintly a problem with a firewall or IPS if TCP traffic is not working for DNS (only first packet received) if other internet communication via TCP succeeds (as multiple chained TCP packages are the common case). Maybe it's the IPS feature of Your device that considers DNS traffic bigger then one package as malformed. Did You disable that feature of Your device? For the UDP part it also should work if the firewall is in Your hand and there is no device that blocks such traffic, thought it's not as reliable as TCP. (UDP fragments lost in the net are not very uncommon.)

Comment: Not using IPS, just basic stateful inspection. I did enable DNS application inspection to see if that helped, but I got the same result. When I get a chance, I'll try and take a packet capture from outside the firewall and see if there's anything being dropped.

Comment: I think you're right that it's the firewall. This is probably my issue, but I'm not sure what to do about it yet. `Customers with NAT configured on a Cisco IOS device may experience issues receiving large DNS query response messages when TCP is used as the transport. Cisco IOS NAT does not have support for reassembling TCP segments. The lack of support for TCP segment reaasembly is a well-known issue that is documented` https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/resources/dnssec_best_practices

Comment: On a different note, other internal non-bind DNS servers (such as microsoft) are able to resolve / validate DNSSec on that domain without an issue. They are behind the same firewall. Curious what they're doing differently.

Comment: Yes definitely it would help to do package captures at different places to find the exact point where communication breaks. I think even Your firewall could do such or at least HyperV host. For inspection I know of some devices that always do inspection on well known service ports if not explicitly disabled. For the fragmentation issue it should not apply if You have Internet MTU on both sides of firewall and the firewall only does not and routing/forwarding as it would not need to reassemble anything then.

Comment: If other devices can talk EDNS through same firewall on same ports using also NAT with same rulesets applying it shouldn't be the firewall that makes the problem. Can also by the HyperV Server with it's stack including virtualized network adaptor for example. So will the same query be successfull on Your HyperV host? `ps> Resolve-DnsName friendsadventure.com -type DNSKEY -server 97.74.110.54 -dnssecok -DnsOnly` and even double check the same query with additional `-TcpOnly` flag and will it show DNSSEC as Protocol?

Answer (score 0):

The response appears to be very large, and they are going through UDP, but in this case I'd set a maximum UDP packet size using the parameter:

```
max-udp-size 512;
```

This will force the transport protocol of the server to switch over to TCP, which has a higher chance of delivering a successful response of larger packet sizes.

You may also try utilizing minimal responses as well:

```
minimal-responses yes;
```

Comment: Tried those settings. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server's IPv6 connectivity is broken in a way that the `domaincontrol.com` name servers cannot be reached via IPv6.

The settings you have done do not disable using IPv6 with outbound queries to other server.

`listen-on-v6 { none; };` only disables listening on IPv6 ports for incoming requests.

`filter-aaaa-on-v4 yes;` filters resolving of AAAA records when clients are using IPv4 to connect to name server.

You can debug connectivity to the nameservers above with `traceroute6` utility, and see if the packets drop immediately when leaving your box or if they drop later.

If they drop immediately, it means your IPv6 is completely broken and you need to disable IPv6 addresses in your server. The preferred way to disable IPv6 on the server depends on the operating system in use and also on how the IPv6 addresses are provided to the system.

Furthermore, you might want to report the issue to your service provider.

If the packets drop later, you can report the issue to your service provider, which might be able to fix the routing for that destination.

Comment: We don't use IPV6 anywhere on our network. IPV6 has been disabled entirely on the server. Still no luck.

Comment: Verified ipv6 is disabled: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1

Comment: What does `ip a` show? The line `23-Oct-2019 17:37:27.267 network unreachable resolving 'friendsadventure.com/A/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53` indicates that Bind is trying to connect to the name server using IPv6.

Comment: `1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:03:29:1a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.255.11/24 brd 172.16.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: And yeah, it's still attempting to connect over IPv6 even after disabling it. Maybe it's attempting to fall back to that since resolving over IPv4 isn't working?

Comment: The `-4` option for named daemon should disable queries with IPv6 at all (even no fallback). Could be it is implemented in a way that does not avoid the debug output?

Comment: According to bind documentation, `-4` only disables listening on IPv6 sockets, it does not tell anything about upstream queries.

Comment: No that's wrong @Tero it is mentioned that the `-4` switch disable IPv6 also on recursion and there are user reports around that confirm that (https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00821). The man page tells generally `use only IPv4`. Thought the kb is from 2018 so probably more recent than the version used here..

Comment: Then it means that the configuration might not be properly applied to the running server.